# Screen resolution problem in Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I had developed the flex application with panel container.

And I have a requirement like, if I change the resolution of the computer, all the panels in my application are auto setted to particular resolution by defaultly. But it should not happened like this. If resolution changed, the scrollBar comes into the picture for panel.

For example, I have set the resolution in 1280*1024, so now the panel scrollBar not visible. And as per my requirement, I need to check the resolution in 800*600. But now the panel is automatically reset to this resolution. But I need a scroll bar for the panel when we change the resolution to 800*600.

Comment: So just to clarify, when you go from 1024x768 to 800x600 you want the panel to be the same size and scroll instead of shrinking to fit?

Comment: Yes Todd, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can cache the original size (1024x768) and then just assign this dimension programmatically using width/height properties. Use scollPolicy=auto also. When user changes the resolution and your browser expands your component's remains the same and a scroller should appear.